# Explanation regarding the formula for the sum of interior angles of geodesic triangle on a cone

Tags: geometry, triangles, geodesic

I'm studying geometry and had a question regarding geodesic triangles and the sums of their interior angles. The book that I'm using is *Modern Geometry with Applications (Jennings)* if anyone's curious.

The book illustrates the concept of the angles of a geodesic triangle on a curved surface not having to add up to $180°$. They state that:

> Let $\theta$ be the angle subtended by the circular sector. If the vertex of the cone lies in the interior of $\triangle ABC$ you will find that
>
> $$\angle A + \angle B + \angle C = 540° - \theta$$
>
> In particular $\angle A + \angle B + \angle C \gt 180°$ if $\theta \lt 360°$.

Here, the image that they used to illustrate this is a "paper cone" where you join the end points like follows:

[image]

This isn't the exact image from the book, but I believe it's similar enough to get the point across.

My question is, where did the $540°$ come from?

Comment: @JeanMarie No, not necessarily. The image that I plugged in doesn't show $C$, but it's also just a point on the cone that we use to draw the geodesic triangle.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Consider the "flattened" version of triangle $ABC$, where vertex $C$ is "splitted" into $C_1$ and $C_2$ :

[image]

(There is no loss of generality by cutting the cone along SC).

With the notations of the figure, we can write two relationships:

$$\begin{cases}a+b+c_1+c_2+c'_1+c'_2&=&2\pi\\c'_1+c'_2+(2\pi-\theta)&=&\pi\end{cases}$$

The first (resp. second) one expresses the sum of angles in quadrilateral $ABC_1C_2$ (resp. triangle $SC_1C_2$).

Subtracting the second equation to the first one, we get :

$$a+b+(c_1+c_2)=3 \pi - \theta$$

which is the looked for relationship.

For the understanding of this part of differential geometry, you may have a look at [these](https://mphitchman.com/geometry/section1-3.html)  didactic lecture notes.

Comment: I really like the picture. Great answer!

Comment: @orangeskid Thank you !