# Euclidean circular sector isometric to a surface of revolution

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces, isometry

Let $S$ a surface of revolution with length elements $ds^2 = d \rho^2 + \frac{1}{sin^2 \theta} dt^2$, with $\rho = log(tan(\frac{\theta}{2})$.

Why is it true that any Euclidean circular sector $\Omega = \left\{ (x,y) : y \geq |x|, r_0 \leq \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} \leq r_0 e^{2 \pi} \right\}$ with $r_0 > 0$ is isometric to $S$?

Comment: Are you (in essence) asking [why a sector rolls up into a cone](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4112801)?

Comment: Your answer is very close to what I am looking for, thank you. This would mean that my $S$ must be a cone: but how can I verify this by looking at $ds^2$?

Comment: Computing $d\rho$ should help. :)

Comment: I got that $ds^2 = \frac{1}{sin^2 \theta} (d \theta^2 + dt^2)$ , so $S$ is isometric to Euclidean plane. But I still cannot understand why $S$ must be a cone :(

Comment: Because $S$ is a surface of rotation, the principal directions are along the generators and along the "latitude" circles swept out. Since $S$ is flat, a generating curve must be a line or segment (the principal curvature along a latitude is non-zero). That is, a flat surface of rotation is either a plane, a cylinder, or part of the lateral surface of a cone. If you parametrize the cone (probably using something like polar coordinates on the sector) and find the same metric $ds^2$ (up to coordinate change), that finishes things.