# Opening up a cone

Tags: general-topology, geometry

> [image]
>
> [Refer here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oTD8Ih054n0)

Consider the cone in the white rectangle, suppose it is cut through AO, what will the image look like when the cut surface is flattened onto a plane?

The answer is the right figure of $OAA$, but when I try to imagine the cut, my mind tells me it looks something like a PAC-man mouth

[image]

Both cases seem to look like a sector of a circle but I can't seem to figure out what factors is controlling the central angle which is being subtended. Is there some way to relate cone parameters to the angle subtended once the cone flattened?

Comment: Another related video: https://youtu.be/Y6caQ_8_frU

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $AB$ is supposed to be a geodesic, i.e. the shortest route which goes round the cone, then it will be a straight line on the unrolled cone, as in the first diagram below

But if the unrolled cone it a Pacman-like (i.e. a semicircle or more when unrolled) then the shortest such route is to go straight  $AO$, round at $O$ for zero distance and then straight $OB$ as in the second diagram.

[image]

This particular case is not Pacman-like, since $20 \lt \frac12 60$ and thus  $40 \pi < \frac12 120 \pi$, meaning that you have less than half a semicircle.

Comment: Since A and B lie on the same line, doesn't the second picture means that we go past B first and then come back to it?

Comment: @ACB yes, but you need to do that to go round the cone (which in that case is best done at $O$)

Comment: You might be interested by my answer to this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3618661

Answer (score 2):

ACB's suggested [video](https://youtu.be/Y6caQ_8_frU) cleared it up, once we realize that it must be a sector, the circumference of curved part= circumference of cone. Now, we know that circumference of curved part is just the radius times angle. Use this to find angle.

Comment: It's not my video. It's by [Presh](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/84271/presh) : ) and if you look closely at *your* diagram, you can see that hint.